# Merge tags [datatables] and [jquery-datatables] or vote for synonym?

Tags: discussion, retag-request, synonym-request

The are two tags for the jQuery DataTables Plugin:

[datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatables) has ~3000 questions, [jquery-datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-datatables) has ~ 1150 questions. Both have the same description:

> DataTables is a plug-in for the jQuery JavaScript library. It is a
>   highly flexible tool, based upon the foundations of progressive
>   enhancement, which will add advanced interaction controls to any HTML
>   table

and the same info page (except one paragraph which I added to one tag before realising there were two tags).

I proposed a [synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/datatables/synonyms) but nobody voted for it despite this obviously being two tags for the same thing.

Is a synonym the right solution here? Or should the tags merged instead?

**Edit 2014-06-24:**

I retagged all questions where [datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatables) was incorrectly used.

Now a merge or synonym could be introduced. A merge of both tags to [jquery-datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-datatables) would probably be for the best, then we could get rid of [datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatables) and the confusion between that one and [datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatable) .

Comment: There are quite a few questions tagged with [tag:datatables] that are not about [tag:jquery-datatables]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatables+-jquery+-jquery-datatables

Comment: Most of the question still are about the jQuery DataTables plug-in (which is correct according to the description of [tag:datatables], e.g. the first one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24143438/cant-get-jquery-datatables-in-meteor-to-work). Questions for SQL, C# or other datatables should use [tag:datatable].

Comment: They should indeed use [tag:datatable] but it means a synonym or merge is not possible here.

Comment: Ok, maybe I will have a look if there are few enough wrong tags that editing is possible.

Comment: @Stijn please take a look at my edit to the question.

Comment: This looks a lot like http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207275/208489, which I could *swear* I originally entered into meta stackoverflow (but is now somehow on meta stackexchange).

Comment: Ah... this happened: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange

Comment: Now there is a synonym [tag:jquery-datatables] -> [tag:datatables]. But I suppose it should be the other way around

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The entire tag info page are an exact copy between the two tags. Thus if any questions are tagged [datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatables) and are not about jquery datatables, that is an error that should be corrected. (E.g. by retagging the questions as [datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatable).)

So it seems obvious that the tags should be merged together and called [jquery-datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-datatables) instead.

Right now it is just confusing that we have two tags with the exact same description, and will only add to new questions being tagged incorrectly or tagged with both tags.