# Why can't I start a bounty on Meta?

Tags: support, bounty, meta

In case it matters, [here is the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260059/1366033) for which I'd like to set a bounty, but I don't see the button anywhere.

Here are some relevant links on bounties but I don't see anything in there that would explain why I can't start one.

- [Help Center > Reputation & Moderation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)
- [Help Center > Privileges > Set Bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties)
- [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

I believe the question has met all of the relevant question criteria:

> If you don't see the bounty button on a question, one or more of the following applies:
>
> - The question has been asked in the last 48 hours. Give the community a chance to answer your question normally first.
> - You already have three outstanding bounties. You can only have three open bounties at any one time. To start a bounty on this question, you must award at least one of the previous bounties first.
> - The question already has a bounty. To start a second bounty on this question, you must wait for the current bounty to be awarded first.

And I have the necessary rep of 75, both on [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1366033/kylemit) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1366033/kylemit).

Can you not start bounties on Meta?