# dataTables, a very generic tag name

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

I ran into a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31874266/retain-last-page-state-on-navigate-back-in-jsf/31876746) where ***was*** tagged with `dataTables`.

dataTables is a jQuery plugin, and you can see that in the wiki, and since the name dataTable or dataTables is generic (at least from my point of view) that created a confusion that introduced an answer *(now is deleted)* regarding that specific jQuery plugin, whereas the OP was referring to another use of a 'dataTable'.

I went to this tag to see if that jQuery plugin is so much popular to take such a generic term/tag. I was right not all the questions are targeting this plugin.

What can be done in this case to prevent that confusion in the future, especially if the user is unaware of that jQuery plugin name ?

Comment: Well, personally, I think that the question in question (pun intended) was formulated in a bad way. The PrimeFaces tag **was** missing (the framework that is actually used), a simple code example **is** missing to (which might have resolved or even prevented the confusion). It was (hmmm **IS**, should remove that to) tagged with javascript (datatables is in pure javascript), so the quality of the post plays an important role in preventing ambiguous questions..... (to be cnt'd)

Comment: Never the less, if there many posts in the datatables tag that are not datatables related, the people following that tag should at least do some cleanup (I do that a lot for the JSF/PrimeFaces  tags) and maybe add some text to the datatables wiki/info to notify people to pay attention to using the correct tag. But since jquery-datatables is a synonym for datatables , that could create a problem in maintainability. But I don't think you can 'revoke' such a tag directly if at all

Comment: I see that [tag:jquery-datatables]is a synonym of [tag:datatables].  Maybe that should be the other way around and then we could clean out [tag:datatables]

Comment: @Kukeltje You're perfectly correct, I have seen other cases also where they committed the same mistake and wasn't referring to that plugin and no one cleaned that up, again dataTables tag is too generic compared to JSF/PrimeFaces one :)

Comment: @NathanOliver sounds good.

Comment: I added a small change to the 'datatable' tag wiki to have explicitly state that for jquery-datatables the jquery-datatables tag should be used and not datatables

Comment: @Kukeltje Since there is a synonym relation and [datatables] is the target, it's not possible for new questions to use the [jquery-datatables] tag, because it will be automatically rewritten.

Comment: I know that [r] has [datables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatables+r) that has nothing to do with jQuery. Possibly some more. The [older merge request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260059/1816580) made this whole tag an unusable mess. A disambiguation is in order, but who's gonna do that?!

Comment: @artjomb: datatables.net is afaik written in jquery. Ah.. So it is not a lookup synonym, but a rewrite. Maybe that should change first ;-)

Comment: @ArtjomB.: [tag:data.table] is the R package that extends data.frame for fast in-memory data analysis.