# Tag confusion - [datatable] vs [datatables]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

So jQuery has a [plugin called Datatables](https://datatables.net/). People are tagging questions related to that with [datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatable). [The wiki even says not to](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/datatable/info)

> The term "datatable" is ambiguous. In .NET, it's a class that represents a table of in-memory data. In component based MVC frameworks like JSF and Wicket, it's an UI component that dynamically renders a HTML table based on a collection. For jQuery DataTables plugin, please use [jquery-datatables] tag.

There was a question using that in the PHP tag. Figuring it was another case of "didn't read", I did what it said to do and retagged it. But it came back up as [datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatables). I had this reaction

[image]

Had to re-read it a couple of times before I noticed the extra `s`. So I go poking around meta and I find [Merge tags [datatables] and [jquery-datatables] or vote for synonym?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260059/merge-tags-datatables-and-jquery-datatables-or-vote-for-synonym) with this accepted answer

> So it seems obvious that the tags should be merged together and called [jquery-datatables] instead

It appears the **exact opposite** has happened.

[image]

[jquery-datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-datatables) is now just [datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatables), which just exacerbates the problem where people keep tagging it as [datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatable). Can we reverse this and make [datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatables) into [jquery-datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-datatables)?

Comment: You bring compelling data to the table.This synonym doesn't seem right.

Comment: I remember that the sane thing to do is to have the language/framework name somewhere if the name is ambiguous. Why the heck isn't the Sane Thing™ done here?

Comment: This is why we expect questioners to use more than one tag.  Which *always* disambiguates these tags of course, the overlap is 0.  No need whatsoever to get this "fixed".

Comment: @HansPassant yeah, and to hell all those that trust their personalized homepage, the tag badges, and every other assumption that the system makes that two tags are completely separated entities.

Comment: This guy will never be able to get the right answerer to see its question http://stackoverflow.com/q/41103619/792066

Comment: I think this is debatable

Comment: I just encountered this too on this question. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49920384/revisions I edited datatable into jquery-datatables and I was first confused why seemingly my correct tagging change didn't go through. until I mouse overed them. The current "datatables" tag is very ambigious. jquery-datatables would make it much easier to discern what it's for.

Answer (score 3):

I think we should do the reverse and make [datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatables) a synonym of [jquery-datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-datatables). At least we will solve the half of the problem: confused jquery-datatables users.
And then we can proceed on [datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatable) clean-up.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that "reverting the synonym" is a good idea either. Just removing it, and then going through [[jquery] + [datatables]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdatatables%5D%20%5Bjquery%5D%20is%3Aq) to apply the new-but-old [jquery-datatables] tag and removing datatables...

On the other hand, datatable(s) is too generic to be its own tag. We should remove it too.

Comment: I didn't suggest a burninate because the JQ tag has 11k questions and [datatable] has 12k. rene has enough heartburn as it is

Comment: @Machavity meh, for that there's the nuke button.